# How to insert record into table which is having 6054 records

Tags: sql-server

I am having one table with 3 f_Key and 1 P_Key with 6054 records.

One record is lost from that table. I am trying to insert record into that table.

The record id is 2352 and last record id is 9560 so,if i insert the record then it is taking 9561 id which is next id of before id.If try to delete the others records then because of F_Key it is not allowing to delete also.If i try to update the 9561 id then it also not allowing to update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SET IDENTITY INSERT` construct to explicitly insert the PK value in a table with auto-numbering, like so:

```
set identity_insert #your_table on
insert into your_table (PK_COL_IDENTITY, ...) values (2352, ...)
set identity_insert #your_table off
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge , if your ID is auto incremented then you cannot update that ID(key) .The only way to do in your case is `TRUNCATE`.If you will truncate the table then it will allow to generate new sequence.

You can create a temporary table and migrate the data to temporary table and truncate that parent table and again migrate the data from temporary table to parent table.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: if i transfer table from one table to another also data will be same i want to add that record after 2351 means it will come middle of table.